# model view controller service

Tags: java, model-view-controller, javafx-2, fxml

Firstly I don't speak English very well, i'm from France so i hope you will understand what i'm trying to say.
I'm developing a JavaFX application (i'm in internship) and this is the organisation of my project.
**view**: (fxml) which has a controlled attached to it
**controller**: launch service, and update view with new data from model
**service**: update model

So my question is: can we call this architecture MVCS? Because i think this not the MVC model that i know especially that in some case i had to create my view in controller and not fxml file.

Any comment on that architecture. Sorry for my bad English :(

Answer (score 0):

so if I understand you have your main view FXML attached to a controller, and the controller from time to time you view objects? And this controller launches a service that update the view and model? what is this?

I think we need to avoid including maximum view components in the controller for what needs you must create view components in the controller?

As against the fact that there was a service update your model I do not think it changes the name MVC

Comment: The service is a part of your model so you can call it MVC if you want I guess.